# I run this junit test, but it fails what's wrong?

Tags: java, junit

this is my class i want to test if the 0<= amount <25000 then theres no tax. but it doesn't work.  the test fails.

```
 public class TaxCalculator{
   public double calc(double amount){
         double pay = amount*0;
         return pay;
       }
        }
```

my test looks like this. i've imported both Test and Assert.

```
public class TaxCalculatorTest{
@Test
public void testCalc(){
assertEquals(0,tax.calc(1));
```

Comment: [@BorLaze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54416062/3788176) has given you the answer; but you could simply have read the error message that tells you why it is failing. Or... it's not the answer; but in that case too, you should include the error message in your question, since that may tell *us* why it's not working, even if it doesn't quite make sense to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assertEquals(double expected, double actual)` is deprecated and ALWAYS fails.

use `assertEquals(double expected, double actual, double delta)` instead

Comment: Where is it documented that it always fails?

Comment: In source code :-) assertEquals(0.0, tax.calc(1)) calls assertEquals(null, expected, actual) which body is fail("Use assertEquals(expected, actual, delta) to compare floating-point numbers"). You can see it inside org.junit.Assert class

Comment: Ah, [I see](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Assert.java#L667). It's not documented, but that's the behavior.